# Why aren't the words getting calculated properly in C++?

Tags: c++

I was creating the program for my friend who is interested in numerology and wants a way to calculate the value of words faster. But even though there are no errors and/or warnings, but the words' values aren't being calculated correctly. For example, "mark" has a value of 9, but the program shows 2. If you can figure out what the problem is, then pls help me. Thank you so much!

My Code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int value{0};


void clear();

int main(void)
{
    int number{0};
    std::string response;


    bool run = true;
    while (run)
    {
        clear();

        value = 0;
        number = 1;
        response = "";


        std::cout << "How many words to evalute?:\n> ";
        std::cin >> number;

        std::cin.ignore();
        clear();

        std::string* pPhrase = new std::string[number];
        int* pValue = new int[number];


        for (int i = 0; i < number; ++i) // could replace "number" with "sizeof(pPhrase)/sizeof(pPhrase[0])"
        {
            std::cout << "Enter Word #" << i+1 << " (or type your full phrase):\n> ";
            std::cin >> pPhrase[i];

            for (char j : pPhrase[i])
            {
                value = 0;
                j = std::tolower(j);

                if (j == 'a' || j == 'i' || j == 'j'
                    || j == 'q' || j == 'y')
                value += 1;

                if (j == 'b' || j == 'k' || j == 'r')
                value += 2;

                if (j == 'c' || j == 'g' || j == 'l'
                    || j == 's')
                value += 3;

                if (j == 'd' || j == 'm' || j == 't')
                value += 4;

                if (j == 'e' || j == 'h' || j == 'n'
                    || j == 'x')
                value += 5;

                if (j == 'u' || j == 'v' || j == 'w')
                value += 6;

                if (j == 'o' || j == 'z')
                value += 7;

                if (j == 'f' || j == 'p')
                value += 8;
                
                pValue[i] = value;
                value = 0;
                std::cout << '\n';
                clear();
            }

        }

        
        std::cin.ignore();
        std::cin.clear();

        std::cout << "\n\n";

        for (int i = 0; i < number; ++i)
            std::cout << "Value of \"" << pPhrase[i] << "\": " << pValue[i] << '\n';


        //std::cin.ignore();
        std::cin.clear();

        std::cout << "Would you like to evaluate another phrase? (Y/n):\n> ";
        std::getline(std::cin, response);

        delete[] pPhrase;
        delete[] pValue;


        if (response[0] == 'y' || response[0] == 'Y'
            || response.empty() || response[0] == ' ')
        {
            std::cout << "\n\n";
            continue;
        }

        break;

    }

    std::cout << "Exiting...";
    system("killall Terminal");

    std::cout << "\n\n\n";
    return 0;
}


void clear()
{
    system("clear");
}
```

Comment: Don't use dynamic memory unless there are no other solutions.  Prefer to use `std::vector` to your arrays.  The `std::vector` handles expansion for you and releasing (returning / deleting) the memory for you.

Comment: If you want to add up the value of words faster, use an array (lookup table) where the index is a letter and the slot is the value of the letter.  For example, `table['f'] == 8;` or use `std::map`.  Prefer to use the array lookup, as each compare slows down the processor.  For each branch (if) the processor has to use *branch-prediction* to determine where to go and whether to reload the instruction cache.  A table lookup is a math expression using zero branching.

Comment: @OP *But even though there are no errors and/or warnings* -- That only means there are no syntax errors.  It doesn't mean your program will logically work.  If I asked you to write a program to add two numbers, and instead you write a program to subtract two numbers, the code will compile with no errors.  But is it a correct program?  No.  Also, and as a warning, saying "but it compiles with no errors" to many means "I don't want to debug my code -- debug it for me".  Not saying you're doing this, but many use the "compile with no error" reasoning to not want to debug their program.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues. The main issue is that on line 70, `pValue[i] = value;` is incorrectly positioned inside the for loop.

Here is a fixed version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int value{0};

void clear();

int main() {
    int number{0};
    string response;

    while (true) {
        clear();

        value = 0;
        number = 1;
        response = "";

        cout << "How many words to evaluate?:\n> ";
        cin >> number;

        cin.ignore();
        clear();

        auto *pPhrase = new string[number]{};
        int *pValue = new int[number]{};

        for (int i = 0; i < number; ++i) // could replace "number" with "sizeof(pPhrase)/sizeof(pPhrase[0])"
        {
            cout << "Enter Word #" << i + 1 << " (or type your full phrase):\n> ";
            cin >> pPhrase[i];

            for (char j: pPhrase[i]) {
                j = tolower(j);

                if (j == 'a' || j == 'i' || j == 'j'
                     || j == 'q' || j == 'y')
                    value += 1;

                if (j == 'b' || j == 'k' || j == 'r')
                    value += 2;

                if (j == 'c' || j == 'g' || j == 'l'
                     || j == 's')
                    value += 3;

                if (j == 'd' || j == 'm' || j == 't')
                    value += 4;

                if (j == 'e' || j == 'h' || j == 'n'
                     || j == 'x')
                    value += 5;

                if (j == 'u' || j == 'v' || j == 'w')
                    value += 6;

                if (j == 'o' || j == 'z')
                    value += 7;

                if (j == 'f' || j == 'p')
                    value += 8;

                cout << '\n';
                clear();
            }
            pValue[i] = value;
            value = 0;
        }

        cin.ignore();
        cin.clear();

        cout << "\n\n";

        for (int i = 0; i < number; ++i)
            cout << "Value of \"" << pPhrase[i] << "\": " << pValue[i] << '\n';

        cin.clear();

        cout << "Would you like to evaluate another phrase? (Y/n):\n> ";
        getline(cin, response);

        delete[] pPhrase;
        delete[] pValue;

        if (response[0] == 'y' || response[0] == 'Y'
             || response.empty() || response[0] == ' ') {
            cout << "\n\n";
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    cout << "Exiting...";
    system("killall Terminal");

    cout << "\n\n\n";
    return 0;
}

void clear() {
    system("clear");
}
```

Comment: `pValue[i]` is used to store the value of a whole word, with `value` being used as the accumulator of the value for each word. So, no, it *shouldn't* be `pValue[i] += value`. The problem is that the `value` is reset to zero at both the start and end of the inner `for` loop, so it can't accumulate properly.

Comment: @jjramsey, you are correct. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could make your program run faster by using a lookup table:

```
static const int table[26] = {  
/* a */ 1, /* b */ 2, /* c */ 3, /* d */ 4, /* e */ 5,  
/* f */ 8, /* g */ 3, /* h */ 5, /* i */ 1, /* j */ 1,  
/* k */ 2, /* l */ 3, /* m */ 4, /* n */ 5, /* o */ 7,  
/* p */ 8, /* q */ 1, /* r */ 2, /* s */ 3, /* t */ 4, 
/* u */ 6, /* v */ 6, /* w */ 6, /* x */ 5, /* y */ 1,
/* z */ 7,  
};  
// ...
if (isalpha(j))
{
    const int table_index = j - 'a';
    const letter_value = table[table_index];
    pValue[i] = letter_value;
    //...
}
```

Print the assembly language for your code fragment, then print the assembly language for the above code fragment.  Compare.

Comment: Note:  the expression `j - 'a'` assumes ASCII encoding.

Comment: `islower` otherwise you will have UB.

Comment: not sure but I think standard enforces that a-z characters are in proper order so this is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Look at all the places where you set `value` to zero. You do it before `main()` begins (which is not very useful, actually). Then, bizarrely, you set `value` to zero at both the start and end of your *inner* `for` loop, which means that all the `value +=` statements in that `for` loop might as well be `value =` statements. You keep `value` from accumulating value.

How to solve this? First, get rid of all the `value = 0` statements inside your inner `for` loop. Second, add `int value = 0;` *before* the inner `for` loop, like this:

```cpp
            int value = 0;
            for (char j : pPhrase[i])
            {
                // ...
            }
```

At this point, you might as well get rid of `int value{0};` above `main()`. That step isn't absolutely necessary, but that declaration of `value` is totally unneeded.

Also, **DO NOT** put `system("killall Terminal");` in your sample code. It's very unfriendly, since it kills the very command line on which you want others to run your sample code.

(In general, using `system()` at all is a bad idea, since it's unportable.)